# WinUI 3 C# app consuming WinUI 3 C++ runtime component

Tags: winui-3

Some years ago I wrote a Windows 8.1 app for the windows store. The Visual studio 2015 solution consisted of two projects: a C# main app, and a C++/CX Windows runtime component, which the C# app made extensive use of. I'm now having a go at rewriting both for WinUI 3.

I created a C# test project, "App1", in Visual Studio 2022 using the "Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop)" template, and added a second C++ project, "RC1", using the "Windows Runtime Component (WinUI 3)" Template. The RC1 project now had a .idl file containing a single class declaration inside the namespace "RC1".

I added the RC1 project as a dependency of App1, but simply adding RC1 as a project dependency of App1 didn't seem to be enough to allow me to refer to RC1 from the App1 code. Also, there was no "references" tree item in the App1 solution explorer tree to add a reference to RC1. So I tried selecting "Dependencies- Add COM reference.." and browsed to the .winmd file for RC1. It allowed me to do that and added RC1 under "Dependencies - Assemblies". However when I built it I got the following error:

"Error NETSDK1130 RC1.winmd cannot be referenced. Referencing a Windows Metadata component directly when targeting .NET 5 or higher is not supported. For more information, see [https://aka.ms/netsdk1130"](https://aka.ms/netsdk1130%22)

The page link advised adding the "Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT" NuGet package. After adding that, the project built OK.

I then tried to reference RC1 from App1 by adding "Using RC1;" to App1's MainWindow.Xaml.cs file, but still it says the namespace is unrecognised, even though the RC1 namespace is defined in the RC1 .idl file.

I'd appreciate any advice on whether I'm going about this the right way, or if anyone knows of an example that shows how to do this. I'm a bit out of date with the technology, so there may be something obvious I'm not seeing.

Comment: Have you seen this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/platform/csharp-winrt/net-projection-from-cppwinrt-component

Comment: Have you seen [Walkthrough—Create a C# component with WinUI 3 controls, and consume it from a C++/WinRT app that uses the Windows App SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/platform/csharp-winrt/create-winrt-component-winui-cswinrt)?

Comment: The same issue https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/discussions/3013. Also see [Windows Runtime components with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/create-a-windows-runtime-component-in-cppwinrt).

Comment: @Simon Mourier thanks I created the app and component and used the CsWinRT approach in your link. So far everything's working as expected.

Comment: @RobertHF - you should answer yourself then